# How do I merge 2 arrays of same length to get values next to each other?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

For example:

If I have 2 arrays like this:

```
let array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
let array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
```

How do I make a `ul` with `li` tags like this?

```
<li> a 1 </li>
<li> b 2 </li>
<li> c 3 </li>
<li> d 4 </li>
<li> e 5 </li>
<li> f 6 </li>
<li> g 7 </li>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a for loop to achieve that, this code creates a li element each loop and assigns as textContent the value of the indexes in your arrays (this works with two arrays with equal lengths)

```js
    let list = document.getElementById('list');

    let array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
    let array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

    for(let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        list.appendChild(li);
        li.textContent = array1[i] + ', ' + array2[i];
    }
```

```html
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically we want to create HTML elements dynamically first and assign it to the body. Then we want to iterate through the array and assign contents accordingly (Note, this only works if both arrays have same length). You can learn more about this Web API here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

```
    const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
    const array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

    const unorderedList = document.createElement('ul')
    const body = document.querySelector('body')

    body.appendChild(unorderedList)

    for(let i=0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      const listItem = document.createElement('li')
      listItem.innerText=`${array1[i]} ${array2[i]}`
      unorderedList.appendChild(listItem)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Array.map and merge both arrays into an object.

```js
let array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
let array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

let objArr = array1.map((item, idx) => ({
  key1: item,
  key2: array2[idx]
}));

objArr.forEach(item => {
    const exampleList = document.getElementById('example');
    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    const data = document.createTextNode(`${item.key1} ${item.key2}`);
    listItem.appendChild(data);
    exampleList.appendChild(listItem);
  }
)
```

```html
<ul id="example">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can create and store the list elements using forEach then insert the created listItems inside ul tag using innerHtml.**

```js
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
const array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const list = document.getElementById("list"); // Selects the list element

let listItem = "";

// Creates innerHTML for ul element
array1.forEach((element, index) => listItem += `<li> ${element} &nbsp; ${array2[index]} </li>`)

// Insert listItems to ul element
list.innerHTML = listItem;
```

```css
#list {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```